# How to bind container of custom objects at design-time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to have a container of objects that will be visualised in WinForms' `DataGridView` control.

As far as I know, I can bind a container to `DataGridView` via the `DataSource` property.

But I wonder, is there any way to do it in Designer? I see a lot of options related to that (like `DataSource`, `DataMember` etc) but I don't see any option that will give me a possibility to choose my own container inside the `Form` class.

I don't want to make this kind of stuff programmatically if it's available in the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataSource is bindable in designer. You can press the little arrow at the top of the DataGridView, and Choose Data Source. At the bottom> Add Project DataSource...

[image]

After adding the class, that will contain Your DataSource, You can set in the properties pane which public property is Your DataSource.

For example:

```
public class ThereIsDataSourceInThisClass
{
    public ThereIsDataSourceInThisClass()
    {
        MyDataSource = new BindingList<Thing>();
        MyDataSource.Add(new Thing { First = "aa", Second = "bb" });
    }

    public BindingList<Thing> MyDataSource { get; set; }

    public class Thing
    {
        public string First { get; set; }
        public string Second { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I selected `ThereIsDataSourceInThisClass` in the wizard, than I selected `MyDataSource` in the DataSource property.

The result is>

[image]

Comment: So, `BindingList` should be a property of the class that is a `DataSource` of that `DataGridView`? Can I place this `BindingList` inside the `Form` class instead?

Comment: You shouldn't. Binding is about separating the View from the Model/ViewModel.

Comment: Tho if You select `Form` in the wizard, works the same way. Just checked

Comment: Well, how can I update this collection from the `Form` class then?

Comment: I have added `            MyDataSource = new BindingList<Thing>();
            MyDataSource.Add(new Thing { First = "aa", Second = "bb" });
            form1BindingSource.DataSource = this;
` to the formload where form1BindingSource is the bindingSource generated from the wizard